# Problemas al realizar un COunt en laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una función donde hago una consulta a una tabla con SQL y el resultado lo paso a la vista, funciona bien pero necesito contar la cantidad de registros que tiene dicha tabla y me da error.

```
public function myFunction($data)
{

    $data = DB::table('users')
        ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total')) / también con: ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total), ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total)
        ->join('cities', 'users.city_id', "=", 'cities.id')
        ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', "=", 'provinces.id')
        ->where('code', $users)->get();


    return view('users', compact('data'));
}
```

Intento mostrar la información en la vista con {{ $data->total_count }} y me muestra el siguiente error: Undefined property: stdClass::$total_count (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 3):

podrías usar el método count() de la siguiente manera:

```
$data = DB::table('users')
    ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total')) / también con: ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total), ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total)
    ->join('cities', 'users.city_id', "=", 'cities.id')
    ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', "=", 'provinces.id')
    ->where('code', $users)->count();
```

o 
Tener tu consulta

```
 $data = DB::table('users')
        ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total')) / también con: ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total), ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total)
        ->join('cities', 'users.city_id', "=", 'cities.id')
        ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', "=", 'provinces.id')
        ->where('code', $users)->get();
```

y luego llamar el número de datos

```
$data->count();
```

Te referencio a la documentación de laravel 5.7
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Lo intenté pero me da este error: Call to undefined method stdClass::count() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\users.blade.php)

Comment: La función count ya te devuelve el número registros de la consulta, me puedes mostrar la parte del código donde llamas nuevamente el count en la vista users.blade.php? y como lo dejaste en el controlador? con get o con count?

Comment: En la vista lo llamo con: {{ $accommodation->total_count }}

Comment: Esto lo tengo en el controlador:

    public function myFunction($data)
{

    $data = DB::table('users')
        ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total')) / también con: ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total), ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total)
        ->join('cities', 'users.city_id', "=", 'cities.id')
        ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', "=", 'provinces.id')
        ->where('code', $users)->get();


    return view('users', compact('data'));
}